# error not formatted as per efm

Tags: quickfix, makeprg, errorformat

I have created a `mwe` plugin to show my problem for `fortran ft`.

```
tree ftrial
ftrial
├── autoload
│   └── makes.vim
└── ftplugin
    └── fortran_mk.vim
```

with

```
cat ftrial/autoload/makes.vim
" Variables {{{1
let s:Compiler = get(g:, "fortran_compiler", "gfortran")
let s:ObjExt    =   '.o'
let s:ModExt    =   '.mod'
let s:ExeExt    =   ''
let s:VimComp   =   'gfortran'
let s:FCFlags   =  get(g:, "fortran_fcflags",   '-Wall  -O0 -c')
let s:FLFlags   =   get(g:, "fortran_flflags",  '-Wall -O0')
let s:OutputGvim=   'vim'
"}}}1

" Compile current buffer {{{1
function! makes#Fcompile()
  cclose
  update

  let sou = expand("%:p")
  let obj = expand("%:p:r").s:ObjExt
  let s:fortran_comp_success = 0
  setlocal efm=%E%f:%l.%c:,%E%f:%l:,%C,%C%p%*[0123456789^],%ZError:\ %m,%C%.%#

  " Don't process any further if the compilation is up to date
  if filereadable(obj) && (getftime(obj)>getftime(sou))
    let &statusline = "'" . obj . "':is up to date"
    let s:fortran_comp_success=1
    return
  endif

  let makeprg_saved = '"' . &makeprg . '"'
  execute "setlocal makeprg=" . s:Compiler
  let v:statusmsg = ''
  execute "make " . s:FCFlags . " " . sou . " -o " . obj

  " Don't process any further if the compilation was sucessful
  if empty(v:statusmsg)
    let &statusline = "'" . obj . "':Compiled successfully"
    let s:fortran_comp_success=1
    return
  endif

  if v:shell_error !=0
    let &statusline = v:shell_error
  endif
  botright copen
endfunction
"}}}1
```

and
cat ftrial/ftplugin/fortran_mk.vim :

```
let s:Compiler = get(g:, "fortran_compiler", "gfortran")
let s:ObjExt    =   '.o'
let s:ModExt    =   '.mod'
let s:ExeExt    =   ''
let s:VimComp   =   'gfortran'
let s:FCFlags   =   '-Wall -g -O0 -c'
let s:FLFlags   =   '-Wall -g -O0'
let s:OutputGvim=   'vim'

function! Compile()
  :call makes#Fcompile()
endfunction
```

with compiling with `makeprg`  and `efm` set, I am expecting the error should be nicely formatted, but that is not hapenning.  Rather I am getting the error as shown in the screenshots

What I am doing wrong here?

A sample hello.f90 with error is:

```
program hello
   implicit none
   write (*, *) "Hello"+i
   write(*,*) q
end program
```

**Screenshots:**

This is what I am getting with `:call Compile()`
[image: with calling "call Compile()"]

After I press Enter key after I got the last screen, this is what I get:
[image: After press Enter in first screen]

**Update**

I have tried to solve this with `gvim --clean`, dismiss effect of any other plugin, and it shows a new empty buffer.
Kindly have a look at [this screencast](https://youtu.be/oEU8YzER6xc).

Comment: errorformat looks ok for me. You have another issue with other plugins

Comment: yes, I realised it. Now the problem is with efm, I am getting 2 extra buffer, and quickfix is at the 3rd buffer. I have checked that script no 28 is minifufexpl. with `gvim --clean`, this is I am not getting any quickfix at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your `errorformat` to

```
setlocal efm=%E%f:%l:%c:,%E%f:%l:,%C,%C%p%*[0123456789^],%ZError:\ %m,%C%.%#
```

the difference is in separator between LINE and COLUMN. You have `%l.%c`, but looks like it should be `%l:%c`

1. there are some problems with autocommands we cannot see from your example (but vim error clearly states it)
2. if you do only `set efm=...`, `set makeprg=...`, `:make` you should have errors correctly put into quickfix window.

If you want to suppress output of `:make` command, use

```
:silent make
```

or install [vim-dispatch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch) plugin that can do make in background without noise.

Comment: I have added a screencast with `gvim --clear`. Hope that will clear what is going on.

Comment: I am not sure I get it. I can see everything is OK in your screencast -- it is expected behaviour

Comment: you see that, at the end, there is no fortran code in the main buffer....its a new buffer and quickfix is at the bottom of an empty buffer

Comment: as discussed in irc, efm doesn't parse out line number and it is "attached" to a filename, thus after `make` you jump to a first error and it is nonexistent filename for which a new buffer is created.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: may I request you to stop judging? Also, may I expect some concrete answere from you in future, rather than comments?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble we actually had a chat with BaRud on irc and resolved the issue there first. Then I just updated answer to reflect that. The answer might look like not obvious indeed.

Comment: @BaRud, pls not rush with statements, D.BenKnoble is awesomely very helpful in this community

Comment: @MaximKim great! I didn’t realize that—I’ll delete my comments. Glad it all got worked out!

Comment: @MaximKim: Sorry for the temptation, and I am sure he is helpful.